# Run Sikuli from button in Excel

Tags: excel, sikuli, vba

I am new to VBA. In Excel sheet I have data. At the end of the every row I have an onclick button.

My requirement is when I click on a button it has to run Sikuli from command prompt.

Which command is used to open and run the command prompt in VBA?

Comment: http://www.teachexcel.com/free-excel-macros/m-47,open-any-program-or-file-from-excel.html

Comment: how to get vbscript variables in sikuli?please help me if any one knows the syntax to get vbscript variables in sikuli or in python.

Comment: It's the best if you start your last question as a totally new question. For other people the thread is answered and out of sight already, I am the only one who got a new question as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know sikuli, but if you want to run a command line from VBA code as part of a button click, look at the Shell command.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  dblRetVal = Shell("java -jar %SIKULI_HOME%\script.jar path\yourScript.sikuli", vbHide)
  'VBHIDE HIDES SHELL WINDOW (BLACK DOS WINDOW)
End Sub
```

Comment: Do u know how to get vbscript variables in python. Please help me if u know the syntax.