# Run Sikuli 1.1.1 script via Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I am new to Sikuli and I want to run script of **SikulixIDE 1.1.1** by *Commandbutton* of excel VBA and I already have tried below method by link  [Run Sikuli from button in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192888/run-sikuli-from-button-in-excel)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
dblRetVal = Shell("java -jar %SIKULI_HOME%\script.jar C:\Users\Sami\Pictures.sikuli", vbHide)
'VBHIDE HIDES SHELL WINDOW (BLACK DOS WINDOW)
End Sub
```

but I didn't get the goal yet and giving error

> Run-time error '53': file not found

in VBA.

Comment: Well, this clearly has nothing to do with Sikuli itself. Apparently the way you define the path too your files is incorrect. Focus on that. If Sikuli example is not trivial for that purpose, just try some simple app from excel shell. For example try to launch a notepad and make sure you have that part working properly. Then you are ready to focus on launching Sikuli with all the possible implications.

Comment: Try including the path to your `java.exe` and double check the value of your `%SIKULI_HOME%` variable.

Comment: Should I write code like this `dblRetVal = Shell("java -jar ""SIKULI_HOME"''\script.jar C:\Users\Sami\Pictures.sikuli", vbHide)`  ? @braX

Comment: It is working to launch notepad with below script:
`Dim retval As String
Dim filename As Variant
filename = "E:\OneDrive\Chaabi.txt"
retval = Shell("notepad.exe " & filename, vbNormalFocus)`

but not working with SikuliX with similar script:
`filename = "C:\Users\Sami\Pictures.sikuli\Pictures.py"
dblRetVal = Shell("java -jar %SIKULI_HOME%\script.jar C:\Users\Sami\Pictures.sikuli\Pictures.py", vbHide)` ,Please help